# Vue&Nuxt - How to Hide a Variable in .env File after build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In my Nuxtjs project, I encrypt my requests before I send them to my API which is written in Laravel and after I get the response I decrypt them with the following global functions...

```
function encryptDataLaravel(data) {
    let iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16)
    // Remove 'base64' part from the .env's APP_KEY
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(process.env.DECRYPTION_KEY)
    let options = {
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    }
    // I'm using JSON.stringify(data) instead of just data
    let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), key, options)
    encrypted = encrypted.toString()
    iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(iv)
    let result = {
        iv: iv,
        value: encrypted,
        mac: CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(iv + encrypted, key).toString(),
    }
    result = JSON.stringify(result)
    result = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(result)
    return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(result)
}


function decryptData(data) {
    var encrypted = data

    var key = process.env.DECRYPTION_KEY

    encrypted = atob(encrypted)
    encrypted = JSON.parse(encrypted)

    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted.iv)

    const value = encrypted.value

    key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key)

    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(value, key, {
        iv: iv,
    })

    decrypted = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)


    return JSON.parse(decrypted)
}
```

To encrypt requests and decrypt responses I use a key called `DECRYPTION_KEY` that is located in `.env` file.
The thing is, after I built my project with the `npm run build` command on the server, the users are able to see this `DECRYPTION_KEY` in source code so they are able to crack my encryption. This decryption key has to be hidden so my sensitive data stays secret.
Is there a way or a third-party library to hide the variable in my .env file? Or should I put the decryption key somewhere else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "the users are able to see this DECRYPTION_KEY in source code" - which users in which source code? The question isn't specific because it involves both front and back end

Comment: Which user: The actual end users... Which source code: After production build the decryptData function is filled with process.env.DECRYPTION_KEY's string value. This is how the end user is able to see the key... My question is there any different way to put the decryption key in my function instead of pulling it from .env file? It really isn't including any back end here.

Comment: Everything on the frontend is and will stay publicly accessible. Use some sort of backend as a middleware if you wish to hide something.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm not exactly answering the question, but hear me out because I think this is the better alternative

In this case, instead of storing your key in an .env file, you could store your key in the backend.

Then, enforce some sort of authentication, whereby the decryption key could be sent back as a response, which then could be used throughout the session to decrypt confidential data.

Even better, you could generate a unique decryption key for every session. There would then be no need to hold this decryption key as plain text.